Does Android Emulator gRPC host support access over network?
If you ever run the emulator.exe from Android Studio using command line arguments, this emulator (qemu) seems to be a gRPC service running on port 8554 :
?
Does that mean that it can be configured to work as a back-end service and accessed using this client window outside of the localhost environment as a back-end virtual machine over network? Is there a way to track the amount of traffic that flows through the gRPC channel?
At first It might seem like a question for the superuser (devops) community but they doesn't seem to know much about Android Studio tools a such as the developers community.
